# How to stop GET on a POST route (laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-7

I'm new to laraval. I got this POST route but if someone try the address on the browser it become a GET route and laravel throw a error. Is there a way to throw a 404 page for a GET request on POST route.

`Route::post('/step2Validate', 'StepController@step2Validate');`

If this route is access as GET "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."
error is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Route::get('/step2Validate', function() { 
    abort(404); 
    }
);
```